# Move imported model to the center of the scene via python

Tags: python

Can't find the way to move model to the center via Python API. When model is imported

```
object.location = (0, 0, 0).
```

I tried to use

```
object.dimensions
```

to shift model, but when model has empty spaces around - it does't work. How can I get this data or it may be a better way to do this?

Comment: Welcome Vladimir! If you import a model, the origin is typically at (0,0,0), that means to set the location to the center has no effect. I assume you want to reposition the origin first, right?

Comment: Yes, I think. In general whole problem - is render an image. So I need to put model on camera view. At first I want to move model to the center, where camera already is.

Comment: Perhaps there is another way to solve main problem?

Comment: Do you have tried this: bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='GEOMETRY_ORIGIN') ?

Comment: Oh, thank you! Just used it with "move 3d cursor to the center" and "move selected object to the center". It works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you import a model, the origin is typically at `(0,0,0)` - setting the location to the center has no effect. The trick is to set the **geometry to the origin** via [`origin_set`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/bpy.ops.object.html?highlight=origin#bpy.ops.object.origin_set) operator:

```
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='GEOMETRY_ORIGIN')
```

Related: [How to place objects on the center of the ground plane via python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24015/how-to-place-objects-on-the-center-of-the-ground-plane-via-python/24018#24018)