# When I import files they "spawn" too far away from the origin?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

When I import a model, they "spawn" a bit too far away from the grid, or basically where every Blender project starts. How do I change it so they can be imported closer?

Comment: The position of an object is defined by it's origin point. This might help: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23931/move-imported-model-to-the-center-of-the-scene-via-python?lq=1 or this one: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24018/3710  ?

Answer (score 1):

Check your object origin on the object in the source blend file. If it's centered on your object, it should link into your new file at the world origin.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was an option I needed to check when exporting from Solidworks to the STL format:

[image: Solidworks export options]

You can get to this by selecting "Save As" from the Solidworks menu, changing the file type to STL, and then clicking the [Options] button that appears *only after* you change the file type to STL.

When you check the "Do not translate STL output to positive space," you can wind up with negative coordinates, but if that's what's required to keep your origin wherever it is in the CAD model then that's fine.