# I can't seem to import a model that I downloaded from the internet

Tags: import

I know about User Preferences. I know about enabling the different file formats. What I don't know is why I am not seeing any model in the viewport despite using File-Import-Wavefront(.obj)...

[image]

Comment: Well there is something in your file given the long list of objects in the Outliner.  All those objects are visible and on the active layer.  My guess is that the scale of what you imported is very very small compared to the viewport scale, and you just need to scale everything up.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32116/when-i-import-files-they-spawn-too-far-away-from-the-origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I can only guess, but if the objects in the outliner are the imported ones, it might help to select one of them in there and then use View >> View Selected from the menu in the 3D editor so your view centers on the object. Might be they're not at all in the center or very small.

Comment: It seems to have worked, I think the model was actually really far away from where I thought. Thanks!

Comment: If the answer worked for you, accepting it would be great.